# knockout model - observable empty in IE 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a set of input fields that are used to set search params, passed to the controller via knockout and ajax upon pressing the 'search' button.
Each input is bound to a property in a viewModel - each one is a ko.observable().
I have code bound to the keyup event for these fields that will invoke the same search operation when the return key is pressed.
In Chrome, this works fine, but in IE(11) this is never passed!
I have also noted that if I press the tab key to go to the next field, and THEN press return, the search parameter I expect is now populated.
Any ideas? at my wits end...

How do I do the same as pressing the tab key in code, without pressing the tab key?
I think IE's handling of the .change() event in jquery might be different to everyone else...

edited to include sample code - js:

```
var searchVm = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.reference = ko.observable("");
    self.postCode = ko.observable("");
    self.description = ko.observable("");

    self.doSearch = function () {
        var date = {
            Ref: self.reference(),
            PostCode: self.postCode(),
            Desc: self.description()
        };

        // do the ajax call to controller
        // ... etc ...
    }
}

$('.searchField').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which===13) {
        $('#btnSearch').click();
    }
});
```

the page:

```
<div class='indexRow'>
   <label>Reference:</label>
   <input type='text' class='searchField' data-bind="value: reference" />
</div>
<div class='indexRow'>
   <label>PostCode:</label>
   <input type='text' class='searchField' data-bind="value: postCode" />
</div>
<div class='indexRow'>
   <label>Description:</label>
   <input type='text' class='searchField' data-bind="value: description" />
</div>
<button data-bind='click: doSearch'>Search</button>
```

Comment: Can you paste some code/a fiddle? It might be IE's treatment of `""` vs. `undefined`

Comment: I was sort of trying to avoid cobbling example code together a) hoping to save time b) hoping someone else would know what the issue was having met it before! I'll see what I can do.

Comment: It is a bad idea to mess with the DOM outside of Knockout bindings. Your jQuery `keyup` should be an event binding.

Comment: @JimFR in the code you've pasted your `button` element doesn't actually have an `id="btnSearch"` attribute so your `click()` is matching nothing. Works for me in IE11 after adding the `id`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agwLuzp8/)

Comment: @swornabsent actually, it does in the real code - I neglected to include that as I didn't think it was important. Goes to show, dunnit!